# Photos not sending when attched to a sms on a UMI Touch mobie

Tags: sms

I have a UMI Touch mobile phone and when i attach a photo to a message it doesnt send.  It says sending but just sits and then says message failed.  Any clues.  Many thanks.

Comment: when you say *message*- do you mean "SMS" or "MMS". In the case of SMS, you normally can't attach pics. If it is MMS, is the APN settings of carrier correctly set up on your phone?

Answer (score 0):

Delete some old messages to make some room. You've reached the limits for allocated space for messages. That's stupid, the phone should say: " memory full, please delete some of  your old messages and you'll be able to send new ones"